# Port forwarding on Huawei HG8245A

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, port-forwarding

I need to make a port forwarding on Huawei HG8245A router.
I've created record in the settings, but still did doesn't work. What could be the reason?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does the router have an external IP address?

Comment: @user1686 I'm trying to understand that, you can see that my ip deteted on a web is 37.214.66.80. But in wan infor there is other ip, but I'm not sure if it what i need.

Comment: Websites will always show some external address – but that doesn't tell you which device it actually belongs to. What matters is always **the address that's shown by the router itself.** The address you see in the router's "WAN information" page is its real address – if it's not external, then port-forwarding usually can't be done.

Comment: @user1686, Looks like it's the case, since router connected with pppoe, and 100.123.35.84 is internal address. I've uploaded traceroute result.